# Enabling Jackson with Jersey+spring boot+gradle

Tags: json, gradle, spring-boot, jersey, jackson

i am currently using:

-spring boot with embedded web server
-jersey 2.22.1 (and jersey directive to map resources)
-gradle

and i am not able to make Jackson work to map json with my objects in a POST request. I read http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/json-example-with-jersey-jackson/ and here it seems very easy, but i haven't a web.xml (and in the link there is a web.xml entry for the pojomapping) and i use gradle and not maven (but dependencies are similar i think).
I tried to convert those dependencies for gradle but i keep getting "bad request" when i call my mapped POST method (mapping works ok, i tested it with a GET request(no json), and also the POST works fine with a string input).

I have all the method directives ok (@consumes,@produces,...)
I am sorry i haven't the code on this machine, i will edit when i can.

How can i make this system work?
thanks

Here some code!

the POST method mapped(there is also a similar one to handle the OPTIONS message that is sent before the POST):

```
@POST
@Path("/insert")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
@Transactional
public Response setRes(Resources1 input) throws Exception {
    testString = "ok"
    return Response.status(200)
            .entity(testString)
            //.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*")
            .header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, DELETE, PUT, OPTIONS")
            .header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin, origin, content-type, accept, authorization")
            .header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
            .allow("OPTIONS")
            .build();
}
```

note that the code inside the method is never executed because the caller gets BAD REQUEST.

Here the dependencies in gradle.build:

```
 dependencies {
  compile 'org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-json-jackson:2.22.1'
  compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.0.6.Final'
  compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-c3p0:5.0.6.Final'
//  compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
  compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jersey'
  compile 'org.springframework:spring-tx'
  compile 'org.springframework:spring-orm'
  runtime 'javax.transaction:jta:1.1'
  runtime 'org.postgresql:postgresql:9.4.1207.jre7'


    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-json-provider:2.7.0'
    compile 'org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-server:2.22.1'
}
```

If you need something else let me know
Thanks!

Comment: If you are using the spring-boot-starter-jersey, you shouldn't have to do anything else. It just works

Comment: if you mean: compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jersey', i have it in gradle.build, but it doesn't work..

Comment: Bad request doesn't mean you don't have Jackson (json) support. It usually means there is something wrong with the request. Are there any logs about the error? Usually Jackson will spew out some error about the request when something goes wrong

Comment: You will need to post some code for more help. And maybe some error logs if there are any.

Comment: added some code, but no stacktrace or errors are logged in the server log

Comment: You need to post any error messages. You need to do some debugging to find one. Either on the client side or look at some server logs. If there is a bad request then there should be some reason why explained somewhere. Is there no body in the client response? Sorry but I don't think anyone can help you without more information.